# Every convergent sequence is bounded: what's wrong with this counterexample?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A basic result in analysis states that convergence of a sequence implies its boundedness. I was wondering: what's wrong with $x_n = 1/(n-a)$ for some $a \in N$? This sequence is convergent to $0$, but $x_a$ is unbounded. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: How do you define $x_{a}$? If you plug $n=a$ you get $x_{a}=1/0$.

Comment: $x_a$ is undefined so that is not a sequence at all.

Comment: You are missing a definition for $x_a$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The result is saying that any convergence sequence in real numbers is bounded. The sequence that you have constructed is not a sequence in real numbers, it is a sequence in extended real numbers if you take the convention that $1/0=\infty$.

Comment: Okay, I see. So a sequence of real numbers can be unbounded only asymptotically?

Comment: I don't understand your question? What is asymptotically?

Comment: I mean, if you really want to say a sequence of real numbers, then you have to make sure all terms are defined. But if you take the convention that $1/0=\infty$, it is not a sequence of real numbers because $\infty$ is not in the system of real numbers.

Comment: I mean that, if you rule out all the cases like the one I asked about, an element of a sequence can be unbounded only as $n$ goes to infinity (e.g. $x_n=n$), and it's never the case that a sequence is unbounded because one of its elements $x_n$ is unbounded with $n$ finite.

Comment: Of course, for a finite set of real numbers must be bounded, just take their maxima.

Comment: Ok, clear! Thanks!

Comment: @TobiaMarcucci: I think you've understood correctly, but to be clear: There is no such thing as an "unbounded element."  Every element of *any* sequence of real numbers is finite (this is called the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)).  Boundedness only makes sense when applied to the sequence as a whole.

Comment: The result "every convergent sequence is bounded" holds more generally. It is valid in every metric space. However, the set $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ is _not_ a metric space if you try to define the metric in such a way that $\infty$ has an infinite distance to other points.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, your observation cleared my view! Jeppe Stig Nielsen, thank you too!

Answer (score 9):

A real sequence is nothing but a function 
$$f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
One often writes for example $x_n$ instead of $f(n)$ etc.

So, your "sequence" is not defined on $\mathbb{N}$ but on $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{a\}$.

But nicely enough, if you remove the "undefined member" by setting $x_a := r$ to an arbitrary real number $r$, you get a convergent sequence which is bounded.

Answer (score 5):

Your sequence $\{ 1/(n-a)\}_1^\infty $ is not defined at $n=a$ if $a$ is a positive integer.

Thus it is not a sequence at all.

for example  $$\{ 1/(n-5)\}   _1^\infty   = \{ -1/4,-1/3,-1/2, -1, ?, 1,...\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$x_n = 1 / (n - a)$ for some natural number n is not a sequence of real numbers as all, since $x_a$ is not defined.

If you picked for example $a = 1000 - 10^{-1000}$, then $x_{1000} = 10^{1000}$. The sequence is convergent to 0, and while $x_{1000}$ is pretty large, it is still bounded by $10^{1000}$.

The simple idea behind the theorem is that the sequence will have an infinite number of elements that are not much larger than the limit, and only a finite number of elements that are not quite close to the limit. The numbers close to the limit are bounded because they are not much larger than the limit, the numbers further away from the limit are bounded because there is only a finite number of them.

There's no cheating by introducing a number to the sequence that would be unbounded on its own - that's not a real number.

Answer (score 0):

I find this absurdly circular. If $x_n = 1/(n−a)$ is undefined at $n=a$, for $n$, $a$ $\in \mathbb{N}$, then the sequence is defined to not be infinite — i.e. finite and bounded — from the get go. Why then do we need a proof that $x_n$ is bounded because it converges? *Any* sequence is bounded given this definition.

For example, if we take $y_n = 1/x_n = (n−a)$ then, given the arguments above, $\pm \infty$ will be omitted from the range of $y_n$. Thus, $y_n$ is finite and therefore bounded.

Comment: You misunderstand the definition of boundedness: A sequence $(y_n)$ (let's say over the real numbers) is called bounded if there exists an $C > 0$ such that $|y_n| \leq C$. Your sequence $(y_n)$ is not bounded because for any $C > 0$ we can find some natural number $N$ which is large enough such that $|y_N| = |N - a| > C$.